# unresolved external symbol cvFindChessboardCorners()

Tags: c++, opencv, camera-calibration

I've included the header files that `cvFindChessboardCorners()` is declared in and a bunch of others but it still doesn't work. How do a define the symbol? Not sure what is going on here?

Let me know if more information is required. 
Thanks.

Comment: It's not the header files that are the problem -- it's the libraries. You need to include libopencv when you link.

Comment: Project > Properties > Linker > General > Additional Include Directors ?
Is that it?

Comment: Yes, you have to add your OpenCV Library folder, and then to input the names of these .lib files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to add the OpenCV Libraries to your project. (Description for VS2010)

First add the path under

Project -> Configuration Properties -> VC++ Directories -> Library Directories

For my system, it is 
D:\OpenCV\build\x64\vc10\lib

Then under Linker -> Input -> Additional Dependencies add

opencv_calib3d231.lib
opencv_contrib231.lib
opencv_core231.lib
opencv_features2d231.lib
opencv_flann231.lib
opencv_haartraining_engine.lib
opencv_highgui231.lib
opencv_imgproc231.lib
opencv_legacy231.lib
opencv_ml231.lib
opencv_objdetect231.lib
opencv_ts231.lib
opencv_video231.lib

and you should be good to go.

Comment: Hey so after making the changes you suggested, the program compiled! however before it could run it complains that the dll's of all those files are missing? A new dialog opens up with that message. Do I include the dll's in the same way?

Comment: No, the DLLs should be included in a different way. The proper way for OpenCV is to either put all DLLs in the same folder as your .exe, or make the path available to the system. You can find more information on http://opencv.willowgarage.com/wiki/faq/#I_get_errors_about_missing_DLLs_.28i.e._cxcore110.dll.29_when_I_try_to_run_the_sample_EXEs_or_import_opencv_in_Python.    For my private system I've added D:\OpenCV\releaseX64\bin\Release to the path environment, but it depends on where you installed / built your OpenCV